# How to use Environment Based Dead Code Elimination in angular on html code

Tags: angular

Basically, if we use environment variables in our ts code on condition like -

```
if(environment.isDev) {
console.log('running in dev mode')
}
```

angular cli will remove this code from final build in production because `dead_code` is by default `enabled` and it is considered as dead code (unreachable code).

So now my question is -

How can we use `dead_code` functionality for html code (on *ngIf) because we can not redirectly use `environment.isDev` in html, instead we need to store it in some other variable and then use it, hence it is not getting considered as unreachable code and coming in the final build.

How can we overcome from this case.

My requirement is, I want to remove a piece of html code from final production build.

Comment: I don't think it's possible due to the problems you describe. Although you could make the variable in the component class `readonly` and the environment object `const` (`export const environment = {...} as const`) and hope the optimiser recognises this. In the end, you'll have to try and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it couldn't work, I have checked.

Comment: Then you'll have hope that one day it will be smart enough and keep it for now. But what are you using environment flags for anyway that it matters? Mostly they are used for some simple text or similar. If you are gating entire features per environment, how do you test those?

Comment: Hope so... my question can be "How to use conditional compilation of terser in angular", there are some blogs on this, but not clear.